# How to change TTS Rate in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How do you change the speech rate in Windows Phone 8? I want to do something like this:

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
synth.Rate = -2;
```

However, there isn't a `Rate` property on `SpeechSynthesizer` like there is in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed the TTS classes on WP8 do not support changing pitch, speed, emphasis, breaks or any other pronunciation related properties when using text-to-speech on strings.

If you want to have fine-grained control of speech in your app you should use TTS with SSML instead of plain strings. See a WP8 TTS SSML example here (3rd example in this section) @ [http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What's_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Speech:_Text-to-Speech](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Speech%3a_Text-to-Speech)

There's a few handy SSML simple examples [here](http://www.cepstral.com/support/faq/customization/ssml.html). One of these examples might be what you're looking for. Wrapping the contents of the `<speak/>` command with a `"<prosody rate='+0.3'>speaking 30% faster.</prosody>"` element might be the thing you need.